# I need help reading in a file and storing them as variables

Tags: java, file, txt

I have three matrix.txt files that all have different numbers and rows and columns in them. I am trying to read them into my code and store the number of rows and columns in Main. This is the code I have so far

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        if(args.length > 0){
            File f = new File(args[0]);
            try(Scanner sc = new Scanner(f)){
                String line = sc.next();
            }
            catch(IOException e){
                System.out.println("ERROR!");
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }
```

The matrix.txt files look like this.

```
4 6
2 3 1 2 5 1
3 1 2 2 2 4
1 2 3 2 7 2
3 6 1 5 1 3
6 5 4 1 4 3
3 3 2 2 1 1
7 5 4 3 2 5
2 1 8 4 8 4
```

Just different numbers, rows, and columns in the other two.

I tried splitting it using " ", but I don't know what to do after that.

Comment: When asking a code-related question, the very first tag you should add is for the language being used. You've not provided such a tag.

Comment: Im sorry im a little new to the site but i have fixed it now so hopefully someone out there can help me with my actual problem

Comment: Have you tried using a while loop to read each **line** out of the scanner (using nextLine()) rather than only the first number?

Comment: use ```while(sc.hasNextLine){String line = sc.nextLine();}``` to read file line by line

Comment: What is the purpose of the first line with only two numbers?

Answer (score 0):

To read data from a file, we will use the Scanner and provide it with our file as input. Using the `hasNextLine()` method we can find the number of rows in the matrix.
The number of rows can be found by finding the line with the most rows. We read the line and separate it into an array, so that we may get the number of rows each line has.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main{
    public static void main(String[]args){
        if(args.length>0){
            try {
                int rows = 0;
                int cols = 0;
                InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(args[0]);
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputStream);
                while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                    String line = scanner.nextLine();
                    rows++;
                    String[] currentCols = line.split(" ");
                    if(currentCols.length > cols)
                        cols = currentCols.length;
                }
                System.out.println("Rows=" + rows); //Print result
                System.out.println("Cols=" + cols); //Print result
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("ERROR");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You will get

> Rows=9 
> Cols=6